# Extract Letters and the first Digit only

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am working with a data frame that contain letters, special characters and digits. My goal is to extract all letters and the first digit. All digits always occur at the end after letters and special characters; however, some letters may appear after special characters. See the example below:

```py
d = {'col1': ['A./B. 1234', 'CDEF/G5.','AB./C23']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
#    col1
# 0  A./B. 1234
# 1  CDEF/G5.
# 2  AB./C23
```

I looked up many variants but I do not know how handle special characters `./` and the likes.

```py
df.col1.str.extract('([A-Za-z\d]+)')
#    0
# 0  A
# 1  CDEF
# 2  AB
```

This gives me all the letters and digits until it reaches a special character. Eventually I would like to get the following output:

```py
AB1
CDEFG5
ABC2
```

I am new to regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract all the characters up to and including the first digit, and then replace any non-letter/digit characters with an empty string:

```
d = {'col1': ['A./B. 1234', 'CDEF/G5.','AB./C23']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.col1.str.extract(r'^([^\d]+\d)').replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
        0
0     AB1
1  CDEFG5
2    ABC2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method

```
s=df['col1'].str.extractall("([a-zA-Z0-9])")[0]
s[s.str.isalpha()|s.shift().str.isalpha()].sum(level=0)
0       AB1
1    CDEFG5
2      ABC2
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

#create compiled regex... just makes it easier
pat1 = re.compile(r'[a-z]+', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
pat2 = re.compile(r'\d{1}')
#extract words and numbers
step1 = [''.join(pat1.findall(entry)) for entry in df.col1]
step2 = [pat2.search(entry).group() for entry in df.col1]

#combine words and numbers, withe the number trailing word(s)
[''.join(ent) for ent in zip(step1,step2)]

['AB1', 'CDEFG5', 'ABC2']
```